# How to call integer from one method to another method in c++

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to make a program that can take student's information(name, Fee) from the user, then ask the user to enter raise percentage value and then calculate the new fee of all students.

For this, I need the Fee details entered in setValues() method to be called in calculateFee() method. But I can't figure it out that how can I do this.
Kindly help me with this.

```
class student
{
    public:
        int   fee;
    char  name[20];
    //member function to read details
    void setValues()
    {
        cout << "Enter Name:";
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Enter Fee:";
        cin >> fee;
    }
        // member function to calculate the new fee
    void calculateFee()
    {
        float rFee;
        cout << "Enter the Percent value for Fee Increment";
        cin >> rFee;
        if (rFee <= 0)
        {
            cout << "Please enter value greater than 0" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            float temp;
            temp = fee * rFee / 100;
            rFee = fee + temp;
            cout << "New Fee is" << endl;
            cout << "Name" << name;
            cout << "Fee" << rFee << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    student std[3];    //array of students object
    int n, i;
    n = 3;
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++){
        cout << "Enter details of student " << i + 1 << ":\n";
        std[i].setValues();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << "\nDetails of student " << i + 1 << ":\n";
        std[3].calculateFee();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user4581301 as I am entering 3 student's data. so how can I pass an argument to a function which has 3 separate values?

Comment: Watch out for `std[3].calculateFee();`. index 3 is out of bounds. Do you mean `std[i].calculateFee();`?

Comment: 'calculateFee() method is not picking the value of Fee integer enter by user. i tried to print the value of "fee" in calculateFee() method but it outputs the garbage value only.

Comment: @user4581301 `std[i].calculateFee()` works for me..Thanks Bro